# How do i fetch my file's absolute path

Tags: php

say i have a file `/var/www/foo/test.php`

how do i find out it's path from within it.
i'm trying to create an "Add To Include Path" action, and for that i need absolute paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Note:** I am leaving my original answer intact, but don't use it. The solutions involving the `__FILE__` constant are preferred.

You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to find the path to the current script. If you need the name of the .php file included, add on `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]`, like this:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
```

Comment: That might work in this instance, but in general, a PHP script doesn't need to be in the docroot tree.  __FILE__ is a better option.

Comment: Thank you, dirtside. I'm learning something today too! I need to brush up on my PHP before tryingng to answer questions like this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the magic constant, `__FILE__`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 4):

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__))
```

Comment: +1 for thinking this a bit further, but it doesn't really matter what the realpath is, will it?

Comment: realpath might be handy if you wanted one level up (by appending '/../') but not on it's own.

Comment: isn't this statement equivalent to ______DIR______

Answer (score 1):

This will be provided as a server variable:

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this_file = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dirname(__FILE__);
```

It will give you the directory in which your currently file is located. File has the full path to your file: http://php.net/language.constants.predefined

Answer (score 1):

```
__FILE__ outputs exactly what you need.
```